# Still combating multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I've put forward two issues with multidimension array before, I'm really appreciated those who had helped me with it. Now there's still a not fixed bug in my codes like the one showed below:

```
#include "Algorithm.h"

template<int size>
void strassen_matrix_multiplication(int (*A)[size], int (*B)[size], int (*C)[size]){
  int n = size / 2;

  int A11[n][n];
  int P1[n][n];
  int S1[n][n];
  strassen_matrix_multiplication(S1, A11, P1);
}
```

Now I got a compilation error int line 5 said that:

> no matching call to function 'strassen_matrix_multiplication'

So how can I fix it? I've modified my codes sevaral times but in vain. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code is invalid and will not compile. Can you provide a sample of real code that shows your problem properly?

Comment: @TonyTheLion:here is all the codes

Comment: But you pass in params to your function and don't ever use them???

Comment: @TonyTheLion:sorry, please wait a minute.

Comment: @TonyTheLion:Yes, it seems a little strange.I'm wondering why I can't make a reverse call.Maybe there're something wrong with the multidimension array passed by.

Comment: @TonyTheLion:can you tell me your email address.May be it's better to send the total codes to you in a email.

Comment: "Code" in this meaning is uncountable; I suggest you take some English grammar lessons (tip: it's called "mass noun").

Comment: @Griwes:Thanks for your advice.I'm working hard in it.

Comment: At a glance, your types do not match. `A11`, `P1` and `S1` are not of the type of the arguments.

Comment: @hyde:Thank you, I'll check it.

Answer (score 2):

There was quite a few issues with your code, one of them being infinite recursion because you didn't catch the base case where `size` is 1 or 0.

I have created some template specializations to resolve this infinite recursion.

Then passing your 2D arrays,  you have to pass them as 2D arrays, because a 2D array `int[N][N]` is not convertible to an array of pointers `int*[]`.

Below is the code and it [compiles](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6ebb23506b0cca3fe76e411e6b44c9f4) with only a few warnings as regards unused parameters.

```
#include<iostream>

// Header file

#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

template<int size> struct strassen
{
static void strassen_matrix_multiplication(int A[size][size], int B[size][size], int C[size][size]){
  const int n = size / 2; //make this a compile time constant

  int A11[n][n] = {};
  int P1[n][n] = {};
  int S1[n][n] = {};
  strassen<n>::strassen_matrix_multiplication(S1, A11, P1);
}
};

template<> struct strassen<1>  {
static void strassen_matrix_multiplication(int A[1][1], int B[1][1], int C[1][1]){}
};

template<> struct strassen<0>  {
static void strassen_matrix_multiplication(){}
};

int main()
{
    int arr[3][3];
    strassen<3>::strassen_matrix_multiplication(arr, arr, arr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have learned a lot from this sample. Wish you good luck everyday.